# PHP Стандарты PSR

Tags: php, имена

Уже несколько раз прочитал стандарты PSR для PHP, а именно PSR-0, PSR-1, PSR-2

Я пишу в процедурном стиле. Хочу знать какие давать имена для функций и переменных.

И нигде нет явно этого указано.

В стандарте PSR-1 есть пункт "Имена методов ДОЛЖНЫ быть объявлены используя camelCase."

Но это про методы в ООП.

И про переменные тоже ничего не нашел.

Вопрос 1: какие имена давать функциям PHP в процедурном стиле, чтобы придерживаться стандартов PSR?

Вопрос 2: какие имена давать переменным PHP в процедурном стиле, чтобы придерживаться стандартов PSR?

Comment: А разве где то в PSR есть указание, что это только для ООП?

Comment: ну я не знаю можно ли считать что метод в ООП равно функция в процедурном стиле или нет

Comment: Полагаю, что это принято как само-собою разумеющееся.

Comment: хорошо, а что можете подсказать насчет переменных?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

И функции и переменные именуются camelCase хоть в процедурном хоть в ООП стиле.